# Get data from olap cube in c#?

Tags: olap-cube, cubes

What is the best solution to get data from an olap cube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Adomd .Net and MDX queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use .Net and MDX. Just have a class with a list of variables and store data in an olpresult class. After storing data you can perform any further action such as linq to sql.